# Prove the existence of complex matrix that satisfies the following conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra

B is a 2 by 2 complex matrix. $B=0$ or $B^2 \neq 0$. Prove that a complex matrix C exists such that $C^2=B$.

I cannot understand what this problem wants me to do. "$B=0$ or $B^2 \neq 0$". Should I deal with the two cases? It would be great if somebody can give me some hints or solutions.

Comment: What this is saying in effect is that there is no solution when $B\ne0$ but $B^2=0$. You may as well then assume that $B^2\ne0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown it's really unclear...I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if $B=0$ then take $C=0$ and you are done, so $B^2 \neq 0$.

Since $B$ is complex matrix it has Jordan normal form. There exists invertable matrix $S$ such that $B=SXS^{-1}$ where X has one of 2 possible forms:
$X=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{pmatrix} $ or $X=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix} $.

In the first case $\sqrt{X}=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{\lambda_1} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{\lambda_2} \end{pmatrix}$ and $C = S \sqrt{X}S^{-1}$.

In the second case $\lambda \neq 0$, otherwise $B^2=SXS^{-1}SXS^{-1}=SX^2S^{-1}=0$.

So $\sqrt{X}=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{\lambda} & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\lambda}} \\ 0 & \sqrt{\lambda} \end{pmatrix}$ and $C = S \sqrt{X}S^{-1}$.

And, of course, $C^2 = S \sqrt{X}S^{-1} S \sqrt{X}S^{-1} =SXS^{-1}=B$.